# wordpress the_category for custom post types

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I have this loop that gets chosen categories for a custom post type of portfolio:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array('category__in' => $portfolio_cat, 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'showposts'=>$number_of_posts) );
```

It uses standard wordpress categories, but only shows portfolio type posts in those categories. The problem is, I want to list the category the portfolio post is in but when the category is clicked it leads to a 404 not found.

I am using this to display the category (successfully) under the portfolio post type:

```
<?php the_category('') ?>
```

Is there any way to have a custom post type use standard categories and not a custom taxonomy and be able to click the category to go to a page that lists all posts in the category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use

```
'taxonomies' => array('category')
```

in your `register_post_type()` function to make it connected to the category. Also, you can use this

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category','portfolio');
```

after you call the `register_post_type()` function.

If you want your custom post type posts to show up on standard archives or include them on your home page mixed up with other post types, use the [pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action hook.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );
function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
    {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'portfolio' ) );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: After checking my code, I already do have the line 'taxonomies' => array('category'). Will "register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category','portfolio')" make it so that clicking a category link will show portfolio posts as well as regular posts of that category or is that what the third function is for?  Also, is that one line the only code I need for the second part?

Comment: Yes, the one line is enough but the hook is required to enable the the custom post to be used as normal post.